# Adding custom action to UserModel's Admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-users

Is there any possibility to create custom action in admin page for django UserModel? I want automatize adding user to group (like adding him to staff, set some extra values, etc.), and of course create actions that take these changes back.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Import `User` in your admin.py unregister it, create new `ModelAdmin` for it (or subclass the default one) and go wild.

It would look something like this I guess:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['some_action']

    def some_action(self, request, queryset):
        #do something ...
    some_action.short_description = "blabla"

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

[Reference for actions.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin)

Comment: In addition, I guess you could also `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin` and then subclass `UserAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin`?

Answer (score 4):

Working example without losing all default inline actions etc.
Here we will add action which activates selected users.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


def make_active(modeladmin, news, queryset):
    queryset.update(is_active=True)
make_active.short_description = u"Activate selected Users"

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    actions = [make_active]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```